# Determining the direct and transverse tangent lines for two non-overlapping ellipses

Tags: matlab, conic-sections, computational-geometry

I am trying to determine the direct and transverse lines for two non-overlapping ellipses.  I specifically mean that the two ellipses are totally separated from each other with no shared regions.  I have been working out a general solution using the implicit definition of a conic section, though specific to an ellipse.

Given the definition of a general conic section:
$$
ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0
$$
A point on ellipse E1 is thus defined as Equation 1 (assumed that $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$, $d_1$, $e_1$, and $f_1$ are known):
$$
a_1x_1^2+b_1x_1y_1+c_1y_1^2+d_1x_1+e_1y_1+f_1=0
$$
A point on ellipse E2 is similarly defined as Equation 2 (likewise assumed that $a_2$, $b_2$, $c_2$, $d_2$, $e_2$, and $f_2$ are known):
$$
a_2x_2^2+b_2x_2y_2+c_2y_2^2+d_2x_2+e_2y_2+f_2=0
$$
The tangent of the conic section for any point $(x,y)$ can be obtained via implicit differentiation of the equation for the conic section above:
$$
2ax+b[y+\frac{dy}{dx}]+2cy\frac{dy}{dx}+d+e\frac{dy}{dx}=0
$$
which becomes:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}[bx+2cy+e]=-2ax-by-d
$$
Solving for $\frac{dx}{dy}$ yields:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2ax-by-d}{bx+2cy+e}
$$
For the two tangent points of ellipses E1 and E2, relationships can be established between the slope of the tangents points and the slope of the line connecting $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$:
$$
\frac{-2a_1x_1-b_1y_1-d_1}{b_1x_1+2c_1y_1+e_1}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1},
\frac{-2a_2x_2-b_2y_2-d_2}{b_2x_2+2c_2y_2+e_2}=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$$
Through some further mathematical machinations (namely bring the denominators out from under the numerators, multiplying out the terms, and bringing all terms on the left-hand side of the equation), these two equations can be restated to obtain Equation 3:
$$
2a_1x_1^2+2b_1x_1y_1+d_1x_1-2a_1x_1x_2-b_1x_2y_1-d_1x_2-b_1x_1y_2-2c_1y_1y_2-e_1y_2+2c_1y_1^2+e_1y_1=0
$$
and Equation 4:
$$
-2a_2x_2^2-2b_2x_2y_2-d_2x_2+2a_2x_1x_2+b_2x_1y_2+d_2x_1+b_2x_2y_1+2c_2y_1y_2+e_2y_1-2c_2y_2^2-e_2y_2=0
$$
These four equations with four unknowns ($x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, and $y_2$) should then be solvable. I have attempted to do so using the [Groebner basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis), as implemented through [a Matlab library found on the Matlab Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24478-groebner).  While the library does work, I have not been able to obtain a solution to the system of four multivariate polynomial equations listed above.  Am I missing something or is my math incorrect or poorly formed?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume one ellipse centered at the origin and "axis-parallel" $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ and the other a circle of unit radius $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=1$. (You can reduce to that configuration by a suitable affine transform.) This should make your equations more tractable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different approach. Choose a coordinate system with origin at the center of the first ellipse $E_1$ and aligned with its axes of symmetry. We can then parameterize $E_1$ as
$$
x = a\cos\theta \quad ; \quad y = b\sin\theta
$$
The tangent line $L_{\theta}$ at the point $(a\cos\theta, b\sin\theta)$ has parametric equations
$$
L_{\theta}(t) = \big(a(\cos\theta - t\sin\theta),\; b(\sin\theta + t\cos\theta)\big)
$$
Suppose the other ellipse $E_2$ has implicit equation $F(x,y)=0$. The line $L_{\theta}$ intersects $E_2$ at values of $t$ that satisfy $F(L_{\theta}(t))=0$. This latter is a quadratic in $t$. The line $L_{\theta}$ will be tangent to $E_2$ when this quadratic has two equal roots. So, we write down the condition that it has equal roots, which be an equation involving $\theta$ that we will then need to solve for $\theta$.

How to solve? Well, the equation will contain quadratic terms in $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$. So, we use the Weierstrass substition:
$$
u = \tan\tfrac12\theta \quad ; \quad
\cos\theta = \frac{1 - u^2}{1 + u^2}  \quad ; \quad
\sin\theta = \frac{2u}{1 + u^2}
$$
This will give you a single fourth-degree equation in $u$, which (in theory) you can solve. Each value of $u$ will give you a value of $\theta$ for which the corresponding line $L_{\theta}$ is tangent to both ellipses.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look in to it, but I really need to solve the system of equations I presented above.

Comment: Up to you. One approach would be to use my method and then show that the solutions to my equation also give solutions to yours. Alternatively, try another computer algebra package. Maybe Mathematica (for example) handles Groebner bases better than Matlab does. Whatever you do, you'll end up with a 4th degree equation.